# Refreshing PrimaryID to start from one after a deleted Row

Tags: java, sql

Im programming a program in java and i have a database in a JTable just like the ones below. I wanted to know if it is possible to refresh the primaryID location from 1 on the GUI interface form one when a row is deleted?  for example below the LoactionID is deleted for London and added again with an id 4. Is this possible? [image]

Im using SQL in java

Comment: When writing column, do you mean row? ;)

Comment: sorry yes i need to edit that tired ^^ programming all day :(

Comment: @user1992697 Did my answer help you in any way?

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question, yes it is possible.

There is no good reason for you to do this though, and I highly recommend you don't do this.

The only reason to do this would be for cosmetic ones - the database doesn't care if records are sequential, only that they relate to one another consistently. There's no need to "correct" the values for the database's sake.

If you use these Id's for some kind of numbering on the UI (cosmetic reason):

**Do not use your identity for this**. Separate the visual row number, order or anything else  from the internal database key.

**If you REALLY want to do this**,

Google *"reseeding or resetting auto increment primary ID's"* for your sql product.

Be aware for some solutions if you reset the identity seed below values that you currently have in the table, that you will violate the indentity column's uniqueness constraint as soon as the values start to overlap

*Thanks  Andriy for mentioning my blindly pasting a mysql solution :)*

Some examples:

- [`ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN auto_increment_column_name RESTART WITH 8 Java DB`](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.6/ref/rrefsqlj81859.html)
- [`DBCC CHECKIDENT (mytable, RESEED, 0)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510121/reset-autoincrement-in-sqlserver-after-delete)
- [Altering the sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159840/need-to-reset-the-value-of-sequence-in-oracle)

Comment: Agree with your main message about not using an ID column for anything else but identification purposes. However, your suggestion to reset the autoincrement value, and more particularly the ALTER TABLE statement to do the job, seems to be assuming a particular SQL product, which may not necessarily be the one the OP is using.