# PL/SQL via APEX Refresh Primary Column

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a query to refresh the data in the table; i.e. purge completely all the data, and update the data.
I noticed that the Primary Column number continue to increase.
How do I rebuild this Column so that the number starts from 1 every time I refresh the data.

Comment: How is the primary key column declared? What code are you using to purge and refresh the data? Are there any triggers? Sequences?

Comment: If you're looking to reset a sequence this is a duplicate of [Need to reset the value of sequence in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10159840/458741).

Comment: Thanks Ben.  Exploring this alternative.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need to reset the value of sequence in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159840/need-to-reset-the-value-of-sequence-in-oracle)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not on 12c, assuming that your primary key is populated via sequence using a trigger. What you can do is :

- Create a trigger with the logic to reset the sequence back to normal,
  i.e. after every time you purge the table, the sequence would START
  WITH 1 and INCREMENT BY 1. using ALTER SEQUENCE.
- The sequence logic part using alter statement (Thanks to Tom Kyte for
  this) :

> ```
> create or replace
> procedure reset_sequence(p_seq in varchar2)
> is
>     l_value number;
> begin
> -- Select the next value of the sequence
>
>     execute immediate
>     'select ' || p_seq || 
>     '.nextval from dual' INTO l_value;
>
> -- Set a negative increment for the sequence, 
> -- with value = the current value of the sequence
>
>     execute immediate
>     'alter sequence ' || p_seq || 
>     ' increment by -' || l_value || ' minvalue 0';
>
> -- Select once from the sequence, to 
> -- take its current value back to 0
>
>     execute immediate
>     'select ' || p_seq || 
>     '.nextval from dual' INTO l_value;
>
> -- Set the increment back to 1
>
>     execute immediate
>     'alter sequence ' || p_seq || 
>     ' increment by 1 minvalue 0';
> end;
> /
> ```

It is just to answer your question. However, IMHO, I would never like do that in any production system.

Comment: I saw another alternative that is to drop and recreate the sequence.  Since my program does not rely on the Primary Key, I can afford to do this method.  Thanks.  I will continue to explore this procedure to tune up my program for later usage