# Store counter in an oracle sequence

Tags: java, oracle, counter, nextval, currval

I need an advice about the counter of incoming requests for Java ejb web service. Application server where a web service is deployed has 4 nodes, so the incoming request can be processed on any of 4, and I decided to store counter value in Oracle database. 
I set the current number of request by calling `select SEQPACKSCYCLETOT.NEXTVAL from dual` and it works fine.

But I also need to show current counter value, and here is a problem. When I call `select SEQPACKSCYCLETOT.CURRVAL from dual` sometimes I get an exception `sequence SEQPACKSCYCLETOT.CURRVAL is not yet defined in this session`.

What session is it about and how to work with it?
Here is the code snippet:

```
@Singleton
public class DbWorkerImpl implements DbWorker {
@Override
public Long getPacksTotSeqValue() throws SQLException {
    String query = "select SEQPACKSCYCLETOT.CURRVAL from dual";
    Long packetsCount = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        conn = ds.getConnection(Username, Password);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        if (rs.next())
            packetsCount = rs.getLong(1);
    } 
    catch (SQLException e) {
        logS.debug(this.servername + e.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        if (rs!=null) rs.close();
        if (stmt!=null) stmt.close();
        if (conn!=null) conn.close();
    }
    return packetsCount;
}
```

Comment: Please show relevant code. and complete error stack trace.

Comment: How many Oracle instances do you have running there?

Comment: @JimmyB What do you mean Oracle instances? Database is only 1.
EJB class is like this:
`@Singleton public class DbWorkerImpl implements DbWorker`

Comment: Please edit your question, and post code in the question body, not as a comment. Nobody can read that.  Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle: sequence MySequence.currval is not yet defined in this session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809247/oracle-sequence-mysequence-currval-is-not-yet-defined-in-this-session)

Comment: In short, you need to call `NEXTVAL` at least once in each session before you can read `CURRVAL`.

Comment: @JimmyB I tested it on a server with only 1 node, not a cluster, but got the same issue.
What session does it mean?

Comment: Database "session", i.e. connection. In an app server with connection pooling it's hard to tell when a new connection to the RDBMS is made, so don't rely on it. Note that `CURRVAL` is supposed to let you retrieve the last value *you* got from `NEXTVAL` again.

Comment: @JimmyB It is what I need - the last value set by NEXTVAL. But I call nextval when request comes, instead of that I call CURRVAL every n seconds to show the counter to the user. Looks like its just a bad idea to use sequence for a counter :(